# Why setting JCE css and javascript compression setting, apache crashes?

Tags: apache, jce, compression

After installing JCE 2.4.6  on Joomla  3.3.6, when entering edit mode my Apache2.4 installed by  XAMPP 3.2.1 crashes

After disabling compression setting in **JCE Administration :: Editor Global Configuration**, it just works fine.

[image]
Is there any way to enable it?

Comment: Have you considered reaching out to the extension developer? While there may be someone in this community with experience in this extension, your best bet is to follow up with the developer directly.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I always considered those options to be relative to your backend / frontend editing. I don't think they affect your site's frontend; so disabling it won't hurt your users.

Comment: Hi, happened to me at with various Apache versions as well. Try installing Apache, MySQL, PHP separately and try different apache versions. It could also be an apache module, not sure how you turn them off in XAMPP

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using XAMPP, I assume you're developing the site on your local computer. There's no reason to compress CSS/Javascript (or use Gzip) on a local development site. It makes no noticeable difference, and debugging get's a lot harder.

Leave compression disabled until your site is ready, then try activating the settings on your online server and see if the problem still exists. If it does, you should contact the JCE developers, and probably your host as well.

Answer (score 2):

As you are enabling compression of JavaScript and CSS files with `Gzip`. You need to make sure you have installed Apache module `mod_deflate` and the module is enabled. You can check this in `phpinfo();`

As enable of `Gzip` compression will add `<IfModule mod_deflate.c>` line to your `.htaccess` file. SO the module should be enabled to be used by Apache.

You can further check other modules used in `.htaccess` as well. I believe is the only reason of Apache crash.

Further discussion of `check/install` of `mod_deflate` is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970151/how-to-check-mod-deflate-is-enabled-in-apache)

Answer (score 0):

**Compress CSS = No** solved the problem in my case. Javascript and GZip compression can be ON.

JCE 2.5.16; Joomla 3.5.1; XAMPP 5.5.19